# How to model & bevel complex cyclinder shape

Tags: bevel

I really need your help. I've been trying to model this shape for the last two days, but I'm stuck with which approach to take. I've come close but I think the topology was never correct:
[image]

I've tried extruding the shape sideways or doing it with proportional editing but it seems off:
[image]

Since I've run into a problem like this before I'd be really thankful if somebody could help me out and show me the correct way to model this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm not too far with a topology like this one:

- Begin with a cylinder, extrude up, scale and flatten to get this:

[image]

- Cut with the knife:

[image]

- Extrude up the top faces, then extrude these faces :

[image]

- Move some vertices:

[image]

- Bevel:

[image]

- Correct the topology to get something like this:

[image]

- you should end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that seems pretty close, can you maybe explain more detailed how you got there? Did you start with a cyclinder or a cube?